# How to determine the output of the following Hex

Tags: javascript, html, macos, hex

Given this content on an HTML site, what tools or how can I determine what the output is of the following;

```
<div id="content"
style="display:none">20%73%72%63%3D%2%70%3A%2F%
77%2E%63%6F%6D%22%20%77%D%22%30%22%
20%68%65%6%68%74%3D%22%30%22%6F%72%64%
65%72%3A%20%%22%3E%27</div>
```

I tried to google the string of hex, and I got various results. From a windows crypto to a trojan signature. But lets say I would like to 'run it' or to check it for myself. Is there anyway of doing that on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an URL decoder like this one:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
You should replace all %N with an %0N (% followed by 2 Hex digits) and place all in single line..

results somethig like this:
 src=p:/w.com" w
"0" heht="0"order: ">'